# Can I use '/deep/' to all elements or parent's element

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I'm using element-ui and I have some needs to edit fixed styles which isn't provided as options.
I tried to modify such things inside scoped-style-sheet and I found that some of those things are only able to be modified in not-scoped style-sheet. And then after I found that "/deep/" can do what I want.
so Here is my question

> Can I use /deep/ to my Top-parent element in my vue page? Or are there
>   any problems it can cause?

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
/deep/.wrapper {
    .some-class{
        /*and so on...*/
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Check element-ui docs on how to [Update SCSS variables in your project](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/custom-theme#update-scss-variables-in-your-project). Does this help?

Comment: No. If I edit values in element-variables.scss, Every changes are applied to every place. but I want to change things in specific pages where I want

Comment: I'm not sure how well is `/deep/` cross browser support. Can you add `id="tweak-element-ui"`, and use that selector to override fixed styles?

Comment: Use [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: even !important doesn't work for me :(